# Method “props” is only meant to be run on a single node. 0 found instead. Enzyme -Error

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

In my react app I am testing my container using jest and enzyme. I am testing createAgent feature of my container. But my test fails and I come across the error below.

Container.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { push } from "react-router-redux";
import { getIds, getAgents, getAgent } from "../../reducers/agents";
import {
  readAgents,
  confirmDeleteAgent,
  cancelDeleteAgent,
  deleteAgent
} from "../../actions";
import List from "../../components/List";

class Agents extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    //props
  };

  createAgent = () => {
    this.props.push("/agents/add");
  };

  render() {
    //render code
    return (
      <button className="ui primary button" 
        onClick={this.createAgent}>
        Add
      </button>
    //render code
    )
  }
};
```

containerTest.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import configureStore from "../../store/configureStore";
import Agents from "./index";
import { mount, shallow } from "enzyme";

it("should call instance methods on agents", () => {
  const store = configureStore();
  let mockCreateAgent = jest.fn();
  Agents.prototype.createAgent = mockCreateAgent;
  const wrapper = shallow(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Agents />
    </Provider>
  );
  wrapper.find('.ui primary button').simulate('click');
  expect(mockCreateAgent).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Error:

```
   Method “props” is only meant to be run on a single node. 0 found 
   instead.

  at ShallowWrapper.single 
    (node_modules/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js:1516:17)
  at ShallowWrapper.props 
     (node_modules/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js:867:21)
  at ShallowWrapper.prop 
     (node_modules/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js:1075:21)
  at ShallowWrapper.simulate 
      (node_modules/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js:838:28)
  at Object.<anonymous>.it 
      (src/containers/Agents/Agents.test.js:31:38)
      at Promise (<anonymous>)
  at Promise.resolve.theI.el (node_modules/p-map/index.js:42:16)
      at <anonymous>
```

How can I solve this issue? I am new to this testing using jest and enzyme.Any help will really appreciable.

Comment: Right now you are looking for your button in Provider. Try using dive(): http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.html

Comment: i need to check whether the function createAgent() is called or not. How it possible?

Comment: have u tried  `wrapper.dive().find('.ui primary button').simulate('click');` ?

Comment: yes. Then the error message is like this: Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Agents)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Agents)".

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are finding the element in wrong way. You have declared classed for button but you are finding it as a element. Check the below corrected code.

```
wrapper.find('button.ui.primary.button').simulate('click');
```

Test it and let me know if you face any issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Use .first()**

example 
const wrapper = shallow()

wrapper.find('button h1 or p or .ClassName or #id ').first().simulate('click');;

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'
import About from '../pages/about.js'

describe('With Enzyme', () => {
  it('App shows "About"', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <About />
   )
  wrapper.find('button.ui.primary.button').first().simulate('click');
 })
})
```